# How to find out the row with max Number in a column?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a sql query which goes like this-

```
select * from (SELECT parent.item_name as name, parent.lft as lft
FROM item_tree AS item,
    item_tree AS parent
WHERE item.lft > parent.lft AND item.rgt < parent.rgt
    AND item.item_id = 6) 
      as ABC
```

This returns a table -

```
name   |   lft
```

---

```
A      |     1
B      |     2
C      |     3
```

But, I need the value C as it has the max lft value.
So, I modified the code as below -

```
select * from (SELECT parent.item_name as name, parent.lft as lft
FROM item_tree AS item,
    item_tree AS parent
WHERE item.lft > parent.lft AND item.rgt < parent.rgt
    AND item.item_id = 6) 
      as ABC
    having ABC.lft = MAX(ABC.lft)
```

Now, this query returns no value.
What is the problem in this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask, why this is downvoted? Does this show that I haven't done enough RnD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
    SELECT name, lft
    from (SELECT parent.item_name as name, parent.lft as lft
    FROM item_tree AS item,
        item_tree AS parent
    WHERE item.lft > parent.lft AND item.rgt < parent.rgt
        AND item.item_id = 6) 
          as ABC
    ORDER BY lft DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: MySQL, not SQL Server. The `TOP` keyword is not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

MAX is agregate function, and not working without GROUP BY.

Try this:

```
select * from (SELECT parent.item_name as name, parent.lft as lft
FROM item_tree AS item,
    item_tree AS parent
WHERE item.lft > parent.lft AND item.rgt < parent.rgt
    AND item.item_id = 6) 
      as ABC
    order by ABC.lft desc limit 1
```